# Загрузка данных, требующих JS через AJAX

Tags: ajax, javascript

Суть вопроса:

мы подгружаем данные на странице через AJAX, при этом выводятся фотки, при нажатии на которые должен срабатывать зум, подключаемый js скриптом один раз на странице.

Если делать без аякса - все работает, при загрузке с помощью AJAX требуется каждый раз снова подгружать эти js скрипты включая библиотеку jquery, чтобы все работало.

Это в корне неправильно, но как сделать по другому?

Comment: Нужно навешивать обработчик клика на подгружаемые данные. Зависит от вашей реализации зума.

Comment: можно конкретнее? на любом примере

Comment: Каким образом у вас инициализируется зум?

Comment: там не только зум.. идет jQuery(document).ready(function() { и после него инициализация всех фиговинок, Fancybox, zoom и пр. зум вот http://www.linkexchanger.su/example_jquery/zoom.html

Comment: Ну вот в success-функцию, после добавления контента на страницу и добавляйте `$(data).find(".jqzoom").jqueryzoom(options)`

Comment: так мы возвращаемся к тому же. Требуется подгружать плагины, библиотеки и пр. Одной инициализацией дело не решается, к сожалению.
и получаем мы в итоге 
TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function
 

'titleFormat'  : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {

Comment: Не требуется. Все функции (fancybox, jqueryzoom и др.) уже загружены, осталось только навесить обработчики на новый контент.

Comment: ну не работает, пока не загрузишь библиотеки!